# Is it possible to suspend applications?

Tags: suspend, ram, swap, memory-usage

The main idea is to add a "suspend" button to the title(behind the "quit" cross button) of the application window that will copy the memory taken by application to swap/local storage with pid reservation and restoring it on application run. An alert should be shown if the version of executable is not the same as the suspended app.
Is it possible to implement such a feature in some future release?
That would be a good feature for big applications and if you want to save the state on in-app functions.

Comment: Well, I know it is sort-of possible in terms of debugging software. With a *core dump* of a process you can revive the process later for debugging purposes. Another approach are application containers (LXC for example) which you can suspend/resume as being virtual machines. I'm no expert on this, but it could be possible indeed using some existing features in a creative way.

Comment: See this Q&A on UL.SE which is effectively the same: [Suspend/resume single process to/from disk](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23078/23363) and ['Hibernate' a process in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2137808/1254292) on SO.

Comment: @gertvdijk thanks for your answer. I'll try CryoPID2. Some new API would be great for app devs could handle the moments on suspend/restore +button.